# How to find the maximum data transfer rate possible from the RAM of my laptop

Tags: performance, ram

How to find the  maximum  data  transfer rate  possible  from  the  RAM  of  my  laptop. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and Run the following commands:

`sudo dmidecode --type 17`

You can just grep speed and skip all other the details using the following syntax:

```
 sudo dmidecode --type 17  | grep -i speed
```

Sample output: for `sudo dmidecode --type 17`

```
 dmidecode 2.9
 SMBIOS 2.4 present.
 Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
 Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0017
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J6H1
    Bank Locator: CHAN A DIMM 0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
    Manufacturer: 0x2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    Serial Number: 0x00000000
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: 0x5A494F4E203830302D3247422D413131382D
Handle 0x001A, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0017
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: J6H2
    Bank Locator: CHAN A DIMM 1
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: NO DIMM
    Serial Number: NO DIMM
    Asset Tag: NO DIMM
    Part Number: NO DIMM
```

As suggested by [@Serg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/127971/serg) you can use the following command:

```
sudo lshw -c memory | awk '/clock/'
```

<sub>Reference [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-ram-speed-linux/)</sub>

Comment: (64 * 800 * 10^3)bits/sec is the maximum data transfer rate possibe ?

Comment: what is your ram type?

Comment: you may search google to find maximum speed related to your ram and `As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid][askubuntu.com/help](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**

Comment: `sudo dmidecode --type 17  | grep -i speed | sort -k2 -u | awk 'END {print "Maximum speed is: ",$2,$3 }'`

Comment: @tarun14110 those 64 bits refer to the maximum width of the *system bus*, meaning that if your CPU has a command in assembly language that is 64 bits wide (remember, everything is 1s and 0s on computer), then that command will go into memory without problems. In other words, those 64 bits have nothing to do with your speed.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the boot process before Ubuntu boots with ESC, and select "memtest" from the grub boot menu... this is a dedicated memory testing application which should give you much more data than you could get with an OS running.